# Esri Data Loading Tools don't generate data loading workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, python-3

Recently, I deployed the Esri [Data Loading Tools](https://solutions.arcgis.com/electric/help/electric-utility-network-data-loading/get-started/install-the-data-loading-tools-toolbox.htm) Python package into my cloned environment within ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3. With the process pretty fool-proof, given Esri's package manager interface, I was confident the tools were loaded correctly.

However, once I attempted to use the 'Create data loading workspace' tool. I kept receiving an error similar to:

> Data loading workspace was not generated. No matches were found.

I first thought that this may be a result of the fuzzy logic built into the tool malfunctioning/not recognizing the field similarities and matches. I attempted to address this by recreating all fields from the target layer within my source layer so they matched exactly, such as to avoid the use of fuzzy logic. However, this still produced the same warning(error). I then, for added measure rebuilt all of the domains of each field to match exactly with the target layer. Again, the warning persists.

At this point, I had contacted Esri support for input, and there has been radio silence for about a week.

Does anyone have any suggestions to try next?

Comment: Update: When loading Pro today, the tool would not initialize at all. With the error message "Class not registered."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an issue with your cloned environment or geoprocessing cache. Follow this troubleshooting workflow:

1. Verify that the proenv.bat file (within Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\python\scripts) matches the activated clone environment within ArcGIS Pro's package manager.
2. Navigate to \AppData\Local\ESRI\localcaches and clear all of the cache files
3. Relaunch ArcGIS PRo - you will have a brief loading screen while the Geoprocessing Caches are being created
4. Attempt to open the Create data loading workspace tool again

Comment: This was posted immediately as a self answer to provide documentation on an issue that seemed to be otherwise non-existent within multiple forums, and also non-existent within ESRI's support database. For my case, this solution resolved my issue.